# Why ng-view does not work in my Angular js application

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Before i added angular-route, my application was running correctly with productlistview. Since i wanted to work with multiple view, i added productDetailsView.html and then ng-view in my index.html. All i got when compile is the title from the index "Acme Product Management", no errors on console. Check my code.

```
 module app {

 // var views = angular.module('views', []);


 var main = angular.module("productManagement",
        ['ngRoute',
            'common.services',
         'productResourceMock']);

    main.config(routeConfig);
    routeConfig.$inject = ["$routeProvider"];

    function routeConfig($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider): void {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/productList', {
                templateUrl: '/app/products/productListView.html',
                controller: 'productListCtrl as vm'
            })
            .when('/productDetail/:productId', {
                templateUrl: '/app/products/productDetailView.html',
                controller: 'productDetailCtrl as vm'
            })
            .otherwise('/productList');
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Acme Product Management</title>
    <!-- Library Scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!--Application Script-->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Domain Classes -->
    <script src="app/products/product.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="app/common/services/common.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/services/dataAccessService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/services/productResourceMock.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="app/products/productListCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/products/productDetailCtrl.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">

</head>

<body ng-app="productManagement">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-brand">Acme Product Management</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>   
</body>

</html>
```

packages.json witch created a npm folder with respectives angular versions

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "1.6.57",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "1.7.0",
    "@types/angular-resource": "1.5.15",
    "@types/angular-route": "1.7.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.33",
    "del": "5.1.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/@types/angular": "1.6.57"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is AngularJS, not Angular. Despite their names being almost the same, they are quite different frameworks. Is recommend using Angular (angular.io) if you have the choice

Comment: Are you able to post some updated code from mine and Supercool.'s suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the routeConfig to

```
function routeConfig($routeProviderr) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/productList', {
                    templateUrl: '/app/products/productListView.html',
                    controller: 'productListCtrl as vm'
                })
                .when('/productDetail/:productId', {
                    templateUrl: '/app/products/productDetailView.html',
                    controller: 'productDetailCtrl as vm'
                })
                .otherwise('/productList');
        }
```

and in HTML

```
 <div  class="container">
        <!--<div ng-include="'app/products/productListView.html'"></div>-->
        <div ng-view></div>
        <!--<ng-view></ng-view>-->
    </div>
```

Comment: This solution does not working, gives me the same result as before, i have edited my post and added package.json file, could this issue do with version-conflict? as @cklimowski has mentioned? In my package.json all my angular types have latest version...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Supercool.'s answer, please make sure you are importing the same versions of the AngularJS components you want. For example I see the angular-router module is 1.7.0 while the others are 1.6.9, and your main angular import is 1.7.9. This can cause weird issues down the line. Use 1.7.9 for all modules/components/angularJS imports if possible, and if not make sure the versions you ARE using match.

Comment: still not working, check i have added a package.json file, do i do wrong?

Comment: Can you post updated code showing both mine and @Supercool.'s suggestions?